# Problem processing OSM file with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql, osm2pgsql

I have an OSM file and when I want to import it in my PostGIS base using osm2pgsql, I get the following error:

*Processing: Node(130k 8.7k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)Assertion failed: (xlon), function StartElement, file parse-xml2.c, line 101.*

How can I fix this problem?

I use the following commands that works with other osm files excepting this one:

`osm2pgsql "/Users/me/Desktop/my_osm_data.osm" -d my_osm_data -S "/Users/me/Documents/SIG/QGIS/osm2pgsql Styles/TC.style" -W -U postgres --slim -l`

Here is the osm file: https://www.box.com/s/5a2qck2fc3tsnszimc4d

Answer (score 1):

if the same command works with other datasets and not with one particular then it sounds like the data are corrupted (maybe because a hicup when downloading).

Have you tried to re-download it? Can you try the PBF version if present?

Comment: No i cannot export in PBF from JOSM.

In fact, it happens when i update cretins ways. But when i check for duplicate ways, nodes or anything? i find nothing. If I use the previous version without update, I will not get the trouble, if i don't update some ways, i will not get the trouble …

Comment: I tried to load your data in JOSM, but get an error also. Looks like the dataset is broken.

Comment: Tested it out, node with id 1312365448 causes the trouble in JOSM. You can delete it with a good text editor (e.g. notepad++) and try the upload again.

Comment: Thank you you found the problem. at this node there was " action='delete' " that mayn't be processed by osm2pgsql.